# Remove characters from start and end of string

Tags: php, string, replace

How do I remove the first and last 5 characters from a string in php?  **For example:** `12345abcde12345` becomes `abcde`

Comment: Want to try manual? [`substr()`](http://us1.php.net/substr)

Comment: try this 
`trim($string, "12345")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass negative values as a length argument to [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
$string = '12345abcde12345';
$result = substr($string, 5, -5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$input  = '12345abcde12345';
$output = substr($input, 5, -5);
```

Output:

```
string 'abcde' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = substr($string, 5, -5);
```